# Organize $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1) ^ {n+1}}{\sqrt n} $ such that after the organization it diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is in the title (Organize = change order).
The solution we have is that the answer is to change the order such that it will look like this:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 5 }} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 7 }} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 4 }} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 9 }} + \frac{1}{{\sqrt {11} }} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 6 }} +  \cdots 
$$

I can't see how they thought of this solution, how to approach the question and why the solution is working (why it converges to infinity, I am not sure but maybe the blocking method - but I am not sure how to use it also).
Glad for any help.

Comment: It used to be -1^(n+1) i am not sure why its not working

Comment: "Converges to infinity" is nonsensical in this context, surely there's a typo? Did you mean diverges? Also, your sum is probably supposed to start at $i = 1$ to avoid division by zero isn't it? (didn't fix that in my edit just to make sure there wasn't some other typo which cascaded into that)

Comment: "Converges to infinity" makes perfect sense. That is why the notions of compactification exist. The reason why it converges to $+\infty$ is that the block $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ divided by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ tends to $1$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ converges to $+\infty$, then so does your series, when you associate those blocks. Now, any partial sum of your series is a sum of those blocks plus either a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-2}}$ or plus a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$ and those tend to zero.

Comment: Notice I mentioned "in this context." Nobody mentioned compactification, what was mentioned was infinite sums, presumably in the context of ordinary real analysis. In this context it's defined that a sum diverges if its partial sums do not have a finite limit. So in this context, infinite sums are not said to "converge to infinity," they are said to diverge. Now if these results are then taken and put on a Riemann sphere, then I'll give you that the sum converges to the point at infinity. But as far as I can tell that's just not what we're talking about right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is indeed a rearrangement of the original because every term in the original sum also appears in this one. Rearranging the series to put multiple + terms before each - term is a common way to get a conditionally convergent series to diverge. Each block now makes a positive contribution to the sum, so if those positive contributions diverge, the whole series does.

As for the series itself, if we take the blocks three at a time, the sum is
$$
\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n -1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n-3}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right) > \sum_{n= 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2n}} = \infty
$$